# calculate date difference in monthwise in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, functions

I am using SQL SERVER. I want to calculate the exact date difference in month wise. I know there is one inbuilt function `DATEDIFF` for this but i want some custom fractional difference like:

```
sDate(yyyy-MM-dd)  eDate          output              formula
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-03-03        2016-03-05      0.0967741           3.00/31.00 (daycount/lastday of the month)
2016-03-05        2016-06-05      3.0376343          (27.00/31.00)+(30.00/30.00)+(31.00/31.00)+(5.00/30.00)
2016-02-26        2016-04-03      1.2379310          (4.00/29.00)+(31.00/31.00)+(3.00/30.00)
```

So how this will be calculated? I can apply this logic by using a function but I don't want to do so. How can I apply this logic in a single query?

Your valuable suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the solution to my question and posting here. I wanted to to use the solution in one query so below is the solution:

First I am calculating the no of months excluding the the start month and end month of two given dates. Then the no of month in fractional from start date and same from end date.

```
SAMPLE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @startdate date set @startdate='2016-10-12'
declare @enddate date set @enddate='2019-08-12'

select 
cast(round(  convert(decimal(9,4),datediff(mm, dateadd(mm,1,@startdate), dateadd(mm,-1,@enddate))+1) -- middle months count
+ convert(decimal(9,4),((DAY(EOMONTH(@startdate))-DAY(@startdate))+1))/convert(decimal(9,4),(DAY(EOMONTH(@startdate))))--start date month count
+ convert(decimal(9,4),DAY(@enddate))/convert(decimal(9,4),(DAY(EOMONTH(@enddate))))--end date month count
,4) as numeric(9,4))
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a mini calendar table, this can be handled pretty easily:

rextester setup: http://rextester.com/ZHTTZ86931

Testing data:

```
create table tmp (fromdate date,thrudate date,monthdiff decimal(19,7),formula varchar(64))
insert into tmp (fromdate, thrudate, monthdiff, formula) values
 ('2016-02-26','2016-04-03',1.2379310,'(4.00/29.00)+(31.00/31.00)+(3.00/30.00)')
,('2016-03-03','2016-03-05',0.0967741,'3.00/31.00 (daycount/lastday of the month)')
,('2016-03-05','2016-06-05',3.0376343
                         ,'(27.00/31.00)+(30.00/30.00)+(31.00/31.00)+(5.00/30.00)')
,('2016-01-01','2016-12-31',12,'');
```

Creating a mini calendar table to track each date and its percent of its month.

```
  /* creating a DayPercentOfMonth table */
declare @FromDate date = '20100101';
declare @ThruDate date = '20301231';
create table dbo.DayPercentOfMonth (
    [Date] date not null primary key
  , DayPercentOfMonth decimal(9,8) not null
);
with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, cal as (
  select 
    Date =convert(date,dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate))
    , [DayPercentOfMonth] = convert(decimal(6,4),1)
                           /convert(decimal(6,4)
           ,datepart(day,dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(Month,datediff(Month,0
           ,row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1)+1
           ,0))))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto
      cross join n as kilo     /* 2.73 years */
      cross join n as [tenK]    /* 27.3 years */
      --cross join n as [hundredk] /* 273  years */
    )
insert into dbo.DayPercentOfMonth ([Date],[DayPercentOfMonth])
select [Date],DayPercentOfMonth
from cal;
```

**Alternate** version if you really do not want to create the helper table, just uses the recursive cte:

```
/* set from & thru dates for calendar cte */
declare @FromDate date = '20160101';
declare @ThruDate date = '20161231';

with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, cal as (
  select 
    Date =convert(date,dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate))
    , [DayPercentOfMonth] = convert(decimal(6,4),1)
                           /convert(decimal(6,4)
           ,datepart(day,dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(Month,datediff(Month,0
           ,row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1)+1
           ,0))))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto
      cross join n as kilo     /* 2.73 years */
      cross join n as [tenK]    /* 27.3 years */
      --cross join n as [hundredk] /* 273  years */
    )
```

Then the query just joins the calendar where the calendar date is between the from and thru dates, and sums the `DayPercentOfMonth` column.

```
select 
    fromdate=convert(varchar(10),t.fromdate,120)
  , thrudate=convert(varchar(10),t.thrudate,120)
  , monthdiff=format(t.monthdiff ,'f8','en-US')
  , SumDayPercentOfMonth=format(convert(decimal(19,8),sum(DayPercentOfMonth)),'f8','en-US')
  --select fromdate, thrudate, monthdiff, SumDayPercentOfMonth=sum(DayPercentOfMonth)
  from tmp as t 
    inner join cal c on c.date >= t.fromdate 
                    and c.date <= t.thrudate
  group by t.fromdate, t.thrudate, t.monthdiff, t.formula
  order by fromdate

results in:

+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|  fromdate  |  thrudate  |  monthdiff  | SumDayPercentOfMonth |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 | 12.0000000  | 12.00000000          |
| 2016-02-26 | 2016-04-03 | 1.2379310   | 1.23793103           |
| 2016-03-03 | 2016-03-05 | 0.0967741   | 0.09677419           |
| 2016-03-05 | 2016-06-05 | 3.0376343   | 3.03763441           |
+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

note: Sample data values for output were not as precisely correct as they might appear to be.

```
(27.00/31.00)+(30.00/30.00)+(31.00/31.00)+(5.00/30.00) = 3.037634408602151 != 3.0376343
(3.00/31.00) = 0.0967741935483871 != 0.0967741 -- truncated
```

Comment: Thank you so much man for your explanation actually i am not using your solution but it helped me a lot to get my desired solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the formula that you want applied for specific date differences, why don't you use simple [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expressions and apply your specific formulas.

Comment: yes but how to apply all the expressions in a single query i am little bit confused here can you have one example

Comment: We need more information - your question has very limited information about how you are using your formula to calculate the output.  How are you deciding to use WHICH formula?  If you've got lots and lots of different date and formula scenarios, then a FUNCTION would be my suggestion.